# Building a small numpy array from individual values: Fast and readable method?

Tags: python, numpy

I found that a bottleneck in my program is the creation of numpy arrays from a list of given values, most commonly putting four values into a 2x2 array. There is an obvious, easy-to-read way to do it:

```
my_array = numpy.array([[1, 3], [2.4, -1]])
```

which takes 15 us -- very very slow since I'm doing it millions of times.

Then there is a far faster, hard-to-read way:

```
my_array = numpy.empty((2,2))
my_array[0,0] = 1
my_array[0,1] = 3
my_array[1,0] = 2.4
my_array[1,1] = -1
```

This is 10 times faster, at just 1 us.

Is there any method that is BOTH fast AND easy-to-read?

What I tried so far: Using `asarray` instead of `array` makes no difference; passing `dtype=float` into `array` also makes no difference. Finally, I understand that I can do it myself:

```
def make_array_from_list(the_list, num_rows, num_cols):
    the_array = np.empty((num_rows, num_cols))
    for i in range(num_rows):
        for j in range(num_cols):
            the_array[i,j] = the_list[i][j]
    return the_array
```

This will create the array in 4us, which is medium readability at medium speed (compared to the two approaches above). But really, I cannot believe that there is not a better approach using built-in methods.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Umm, without checking, I'd take a guess that if you use `my_array = numpy.array(((1, 3), (2.4, -1)))` (ie, using tuples instead of lists), there could be less overhead - as in CPython I believe tuples can be optimised slightly better than lists (but don't quote me!)

Comment: @JonClements there's not really much of a difference according to my tests.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe it would help to statically initialize those arrays (ie, once globally, instead of once per function call)?

Comment: @JonClements -- There is a difference between `list` and `tuple` creation, but it's only on the order of 5% or so in my tests.

Comment: @David Wolever - In the actual application, the matrix entries are generated by calculations, f(i). I am doing a transfer-matrix-method calculation, which is organized by using 2x2 matrices. https://github.com/sbyrnes321/tmm/commit/807a370a94ed3f18986f0521f15d49126b63d0d7 - this is my commit related to the issue in question. Speed is not remotely as important as clarity, flexibility, correctness. Most calculations run instantly; it's just an occasional annoyance when I want to average many wavelengths and angles. So if there's an obvious bottleneck I might as well try to fix it!

Comment: fyi, I put up a numpy enhancement request based on this discussion ... http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2238

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a great question.  I can't find anything which will approach the speed of your completely unrolled solution (**edit** *@BiRico was able to come up with something close.  See comments and update* :).  Here are a bunch of different options that I (and others) came up with and associated timings:

```
import numpy as np

def f1():
    "np.array + nested lists"
    my_array = np.array([[1, 3], [2.4, -1]])

def f2():
    "np.array + nested tuples"
    my_array = np.array(((1, 3), (2.4, -1)))

def f3():
    "Completely unrolled"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2),dtype=float)
    my_array[0,0] = 1
    my_array[0,1] = 3
    my_array[1,0] = 2.4
    my_array[1,1] = -1

def f4():
    "empty + ravel + list"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2),dtype=float)
    my_array.ravel()[:] = [1,3,2.4,-1]

def f5():
    "empty + ravel + tuple"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2),dtype=float)
    my_array.ravel()[:] = (1,3,2.4,-1)

def f6():
    "empty + slice assignment"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2),dtype=float)
    my_array[0,:] = (1,3)
    my_array[1,:] = (2.4,-1)

def f7():
    "empty + index assignment"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2),dtype=float)
    my_array[0] = (1,3)
    my_array[1] = (2.4,-1)

def f8():
    "np.array + flat list + reshape"
    my_array = np.array([1, 3, 2.4, -1]).reshape((2,2))

def f9():
    "np.empty + ndarray.flat  (Pierre GM)"
    my_array = np.empty((2,2), dtype=float)
    my_array.flat = (1,3,2.4,-1)

def f10():
    "np.fromiter (Bi Roco)"
    my_array = np.fromiter((1,3,2.4,-1), dtype=float).reshape((2,2))

import timeit
results = {}
for i in range(1,11):
    func_name = 'f%d'%i
    my_import = 'from __main__ import %s'%func_name
    func_doc = globals()[func_name].__doc__
    results[func_name] = (timeit.timeit(func_name+'()',
                                        my_import,
                                        number=100000),
                          '\t'.join((func_name,func_doc)))

for result in sorted(results.values()):
    print '\t'.join(map(str,result))
```

And the important timings:

On Ubuntu Linux, Core i7:

```
0.158674955368  f3  Completely unrolled
0.225094795227  f10 np.fromiter (Bi Roco)
0.737828969955  f8  np.array + flat list + reshape
0.782918930054  f5  empty + ravel + tuple
0.786983013153  f9  np.empty + ndarray.flat  (Pierre GM)
0.814703941345  f4  empty + ravel + list
1.2375421524    f7  empty + index assignment
1.32230591774   f2  np.array + nested tuples
1.3752617836    f6  empty + slice assignment
1.39459013939   f1  np.array + nested lists
```

Comment: I wonder who `my_array = np.fromiter([1,3,2.4,-1], dtype=float).reshape((2,2))` would do.

Comment: @BiRico -- Nice work.  You shaved half a second off my next best option with that one.

Comment: In case of bigger arrays, it might be worth to use the `count` keyword of the `fromiter`-method: `my_array = np.fromiter([1,3,2.4,-1], dtype=float, count=4).reshape((2,2))` This does not help on 2x2 arrays, but 4x4 are already a bit faster.

Comment: `my_array = np.frombuffer(struct.pack('4d', 1, 3, 2.4, -1), dtype=float).reshape((2,2))` is almost as fast as `fromiter`; if `s = struct.Struct('4d')` is predefined even sometimes a bit faster, but Bi Rico’s method is much better readable.

Answer (score 0):

Although apparently counter-intuitive, the results are not that surprising: NumPy isn't designed to handle large numbers of very small arrays. Instead, it was designed to manipulate larger arrays of data.

I would suggest to create a large array first, of size say `N*2*2`, fill it with your data and  then reshape it to `(N,2,2)`.

---

As a side note, you may want to try

```
def f10():
    mine = np.empty((2,2), dtype=float)
    mine.flat = (1,3,2.4,-1)
```

The `.flat` method should be significantly more efficient than the `.ravel()[:]=...` method (my personal test shows it's the same order as @mgilson `f3`).

Comment: I actually thought of `.flat`, but I didn't bother to timeit (not sure why).  Anyway, I've added it to my little benchmark above (with proper citation).  However, it really doesn't perform better than `ravel` for me (It's actually approximately 1% slower, but that's probably within the error bars of the experiment).  Is there any reason that you think it should be "significantly more efficient than the `.ravel()[:]=...`" method?

Comment: I used ipython's `%timeit` magic method, which doesn't show that much difference from one version to another... Anyhow: `.flat` uses an iterator when `.ravel()[:]` flattens the array, then calls `__setitem__`. I would really expect `.flat` to be more efficient